# PyTorch - to NumPy yields unsized object?

Tags: numpy, pytorch, numpy-ndarray

Converting a PyTorch tensor to NumPy I get

```
print(nn_result.shape)
# (2433, 2)
np_result = torch.argmax(nn_result).numpy()
type(np_result)
# <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(len(np_result))
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Why? I thought per documentation the `numpy()` function would return a proper `ndarray`, yet it seems to be incomplete somehow?

Comment: I am a bit of a newbie here. What I observed was that using .numpy() sometimes resulted in an array of arrays. I fixed the above error by doing something along the lines - 

`np_result = np.array(np_result)`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you'd want to use `torch.argmax(nn_result, dim=1)` ? Since `dim` defaults to 0, it returns just a single number constructed as a tensor. Let me illustrate with the below example:

```py
>>> x = np.array(1)
>>> x.shape
()
>>> len(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: len() of unsized object
>>> x = np.array([1])
>>> x.shape
(1,)
>>> len(x)
1
```

Essentially `np.array` will take up any `object` type that you construct with. In the first case, object is not an array because of which you do not see a valid shape. Since it is not an array calling `len` throws an error.

`torch.argmax` with `dim=0` returns a tensor as seen in the first case of the above example and hence the error.